# "I am poor in english" or "I am poor at english" Which one is correct?

Tags: word-usage

Well the title pretty much speaks for itself. Also all kinds of other suggestions are accepted. I just want to know the correct usage.

Comment: Neither is: they’ve been emajusculated.

Comment: 'I speak English poorly' is the most eloquent construction.

Answer (score 1):

By analogy:

Sports take 'at' (I'm lousy at [playing] football) - referring to the verb 'to play'.
School subjects take 'in' (I was bored in Chemistry [class]) - referring to the noun 'class'.

Is there a related connection in your two phrases that would give you reason to choose one over the other? Eg:

'I'm poor at [speaking] English' - 'I'm poor in [spoken] English'.

The grammatical parallels aren't exact, but you should see where I'm coming from.

Answer (score 0):

'I am poor at English' is the favoured expression, but it is not entirely incorrect to say 'I am poor in English'. Some people might say that. Personally I do not like it as much.